# maven: Configuring a plugin in parent POM to execute a task for all child modules

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have following maven project structure. Root POM refers to my-modules, which in turn refers to its child modules.

```
---POM
   |
   |--my-modules
        |--POM
        |
        |---module1
           |
           |--POM
        |---module2
           |
           |--POM
        ....
        ....
```

In POM of each child modules(module1, module 2....), I have configured a plugin to perform some task. So task is same for all child modules, except module name, version etc.

I think is it possible to move it to some common place, like POM in my-modules or root POM.

Is it feasible?

Comment: First what kind of "task" do you need to run? The configuration can be done in your root pom (my-module) the execution can be added in child pom's where it's needed...

Comment: 'task' is to copy generated artifacts in a directory(other than target). artifact for every child module has its own name and  version.

Comment: Why? do you need to copy into other directories? Sounds wrong...

Comment: We need to do it as part of a docker image build process. We copy artifacts in a directory, and then use that directory in dockerfile for COPYING to docker image.

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario there are two possibile best practices:

1. Place the plugin into the module `my-modules` pom file (as you already done) to get it working for each children module.
2. Define the plugin configuration into the root pom by the `build -> pluginManagement` section then activate it on each required module by the  `build -> plugins` section providing only the plugin **groupId** and **artificatId**.

Here an example of the 2nd solution:

**root.pom**

```xml
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>some-group</groupId>
        <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>some-version</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Some settings -->
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
     <plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

**module1.xml**

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>some-group</groupId>
       <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```